# applyImpulse Not Working

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift4

I have an SKShapeNode that I'm not able to apply an impulse to. What's my problem? Thanks

Code:

```
        var ball = SKShapeNode()

        ball.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x:-ballWidth/2, y: -ballHeight/2, width: ballWidth, height: ballHeight), cornerRadius: 64).cgPath
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(ballWidth / 2));
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory
        ball.isHidden = false
        ball.fillColor = UIColor.blue
        ball.strokeColor = UIColor.white
        ball.lineWidth = 10
        ball.name = "ball"
        ball.zPosition = 0



        addChild(ball)

        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false` means to ignore impulses and other forces.  You need to set this to true.